# How to make enough space in empty column?

Tags: tables

As I am trying to make a simple table in Latex, I realize the empty column that I created has a really small width. Is there a way that I can increase the space in empty column?

[image]

Comment: Show us the table. It's the only way we can understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Ideally show us the table in the form of a [complete, but minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: I just added a picture

Comment: The actual LaTeX code is more useful, actually.  But maybe try something like a `p`-column specifier (e.g., instead of having `{|l|l|}`, try something like `{|l|p{1cm}|}`.  But, really, it helps to see your actual input/code.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `Vpp` and `Vrms` should most likely be `$V_{\textrm{pp}}$` and `$V_{\textrm{rms}}$` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Create a single-column `tabular`, and specify the width of the space between the right-side double-line:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|@{\hspace{1em}}|}
  \hline
  A \\
  \hline
  B \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|l|@{\hspace{2em}}|}
  \hline
  A \\
  \hline
  B \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to put a header of the blank column?

Comment: @alhelal: Consider [this code](https://pastebin.com/Tkwtzrs7) ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lRHS.png)).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the same width for both columns, you could just insert an `\hphantom` with the content of the widest left site input.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % fixing the gaps in the vertical lines.

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        A & \hphantom{A} \\
        \hline
        B & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives. With the first

```
\newcommand{\wb}[1]{#1&\phantom{#1}}
```

the second column will have exactly the same width as the first one, because at each row we add a phantom with the same contents.

With the other possibility

```
\newcommand{\wb}[1]{#1&\hspace{1cm}}
```

the second column will have a fixed width, 1cm in this case.

In the example I use `\renewcommand` just to show both possibilities in the same document. This shows also that using macros leaves you free to decide the format until the last moment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\wb}[1]{#1&\phantom{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\wb{A} \\
\hline
\wb{B} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\wb{Vpp} \\
\hline
\wb{Vrms} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\wb}[1]{#1&\hspace{1cm}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\wb{A} \\
\hline
\wb{B} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\wb{Vpp} \\
\hline
\wb{Vrms} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]