# Empty tabular for worksheet

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a tabular (7 rows, 4 columns) that is empty so the students can fill it out on a sheet. What I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224510/how-to-make-enough-space-in-empty-column) in this forum:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|@{\hspace{10em}}|}   
\hline   A \\   
\hline   B \\   
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This will set the hspace properly (after the first column which I also want to be big), but I also want it vertically to be bigger, so that every cell is big enough to write something in. If possible I want to do it without installing a package.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! To get a real [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) you have to add your preamble. - I think [Increase LaTeX table row height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159257/124842) should solve your problem.

Comment: Do you use any particular document class? Please also convey a sense of what "big enough to write something in" means to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My minimal approach would be to set `\arraystretch` to a bigger value than 1:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\bgroup% to limit the scope of the `\arraystretch` change
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}[]{|l|@{\hspace{10em}}|}
  \hline
  A \\
  \hline
  B \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

To also increase the width of the first column, I would use the `p` column specifier which takes the width as an argument:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}[]{|p{10em}|@{\hspace{10em}}|}
  \hline
  A \\
  \hline
  B \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you give a table and code with column header?

Comment: @alhelal I don't understand your request. Could you please ask a follow up question?

Comment: see this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419892/how-to-give-a-header-to-the-blank-column/419893#419893

Answer (score 1):

You can also add some space *after* the row with `[...]` after `\\`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*4{|p{7em}}|}
  \hline
  A &&&\\[14pt]
  \hline
  B &&&\\[14pt]
  \hline
  C &&&\\[14pt]
  \hline
  D &&&\\[14pt]
  \hline
  E &&&\\[14pt]
  \hline
  F &&&\\[14pt]
  \hline
  G &&&\\[14pt]
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]